# error : expected primary expression before '.' token

Tags: c++, structure

I want to sort structure in C++ . Here is my struct .

```
struct Route
{
    string name;
    int cond;
    double value;

}Route_cal[400];
```

My comparator function is as follows :

```
bool customer_sorter(Route const& lhs, Route  const& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.value != rhs.value)
        return lhs.value < rhs.value;
}
```

I want to sort the structure by the following code :

```
std::sort(Route.begin(),Route.end(), &customer_sorter);
```

By surprisingly an error is generated . The error is as follows :

```
error : expected primary expression before '.' token
```

A snapshot of my error is as follows :

[image]
Why do I have the error ? Can you please help me in this purpose ?

Comment: There's no `-` token anywhere in your code. Can you please post more code for context?

Comment: `Route` doesn't have `begin()` and `end()` functions. Not to mention `Route` is a type, not an object (unless you named some object `Route` for some reason).

Comment: I would say search your file for `'-'` token. It doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: as @chris has already said `Route` is a type, not a variable/object name!

Comment: That error message says `expected primary-expression before '.' token`, not before `-` token. :-)

Comment: Your `customer_sorter` is broken. You need to return a boolean *always*.

Comment: `Route` is  type, not an instance. You can't say this: `std::sort(Route.begin(),Route.end(), &customer_sorter);`

Comment: To be more specific, you want something like: `std::sort(std::begin(Route_cal), std::end(Route_cal), &custom_sorter);` (note that since you've defined `Route_cal` as an array, you need to use `std::begin`/`std::end`, not `xxx.begin()`/`xxx.end()`). While you're at it, you probably also want to make `custom_sorter` a class that overloads `operator()`, and pass an instance of that class instead of using a function.

Comment: @JerryCoffin , I am using " std::sort(std::begin(Route_cal), std::end(Route_cal), &custom_sorter); " syntax . But the error is as following : " eror : begin is not a member of std"

Comment: You need C++11 support to enable `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Comment: @osimerpothe: In that case, either you're not including the right header, or you're using too old of a compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should type it like this

```
std::sort(Route_cal,Route_cal+n,customer_sorter)
```

where `n` is a number of elements in the array.

Because `Route_cal` is an array not `Route` (it is a struct).

Array don't have `.begin()` and `.end()` function.

You don't need `&` before customer_sorter (name of function is an reference to it)